# unrecognized selector sent to instance setLanguage

Tags: objective-c, core-data, unrecognized-selector

Help me. I don't know what is append :S
I just want to set category language

```
- (WSCategory*)importCategory:(NSDictionary*)dictionary withLanguage:(WSLanguage * )language
{
    WSCategory *category = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"WSCategory"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:[CoreDataUtils sharedInstance].managedObjectContext];
    category.id = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
    category.name = [dictionary objectForKey:@"name"];
    category.language = language;
    return category;
}
```

[image: console error]

[image: database entities]

Comment: `category.language_id` vs `category.language`?

Comment: YESS!! Was that.
I don't thought about this couse my WSCategory class is like that:
class  WSLanguage;

interface WSCategory : NSManagedObject

property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
property (nonatomic, retain) WSLanguage * language;

end
thank you so much

Comment: Regenerate theses files from your datamodel file.

Comment: how can i generate?

Comment: Xcode Generated Subclasses part of https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1 ?